# Android multiple file download and simultaneously update ui

Tags: android, service, download, android-jobscheduler

I am developing an application with a content download feature. The requirement is to download more than 100 files (gif, image, video) with a single click of download. For this, I am using download manager, but the app is getting frozen.

Is there any other way to download and update(loader, download status) UI simultaneously, and which is the best way to do it(service, job scheduler.. anything else)?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `I am using download manager` Ok. But you did not tell that you were updating the ui too. Nor did you tell how exactly you want to update the gui.

Comment: Show your code maybe?